# ucwords not capitalizing accented letters

Tags: php

I have a string with all letters capitalized. I'm using the ucwords() and the mb_strtolower() functions to capitalize only the first letter of a string. But I'm having some problems when the first letter of a word have a accent. For example:

```
ucwords(mb_strtolower('GRANDE ÁRVORE')); //outputs 'Grande árvore'
```

Why the first letter of the second word is not being capitalized? What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Case conversion is harder than you think. Did you try [`mb_convert_case()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-case.php) with the title mode?

Comment: It works alright for me: `echo ucwords(mb_strtolower('GRANDE ÁRVORE'));` result `Grande Árvore`. Try to turn on displaying of errors and tell us if any error shows up.

Comment: @Chorochrondochor Nope doesn't work for me either.

Comment: @RahilWazir Might be due to locale settings.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`ucwords` is one of the core PHP functions which is blissfully oblivious to non-ASCII or non-Latin-1 encodings.* For handling multibyte strings and/or non-ASCII strings, you should use the multibyte aware `mb_convert_case`:

```
mb_convert_case($str, MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8')
// your string encoding here --------^^^^^^^
```

<sub>* I'm not entirely sure whether it works only with ASCII or at least with Latin-1, but I wouldn't even bother to find out.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to only capitalize the first letter only, here's a way to achieve it :

```
$s = "économie collégiale"
mb_strtoupper( mb_substr( $s, 0, 1 )) . mb_substr( $s, 1 )
// output : Économie collégiale
```

Answer (score -1):

`ucwords` doesn't recognize the accented character. Try using `mb_convert_case`.

```
$str = 'GRANDE ÁRVORE';

function ucwords_accent($string)
{
    if (mb_detect_encoding($string) != 'UTF-8') {
        $string = mb_convert_case(utf8_encode($string), MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8');
    } else {
        $string = mb_convert_case($string, MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8');
    }
    return $string;
}

echo ucwords_accent($str);
```

Comment: What are you doing with that encoding detection and conversion there?! *"If the string is UTF-8 encoded, utf8_encode it..."*...?!

Comment: @deceze Thanks for spotting the mistake, updated answer.

Comment: It's still not great. 1) `mb_detect_encoding` is anything but reliable, 2) if it's *not* UTF-8 it *could* be anything, but `utf8_encode` only handles Latin-1, 3) instead of converting the string you could simply change the third parameter of `mb_convert_case` to whatever encoding your string is in, 4) you should *know* what encoding your string is in and not need to guess and test in the first place.